# Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key issue

Tags: ios, swift, cfbundleidentifier

After uploading archive file of my app, I got this error:

Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key - The bundle at '/Payload/App_Name/Target Support Files/Alamofire/Info.plist' does not contain a bundle executable. If this bundle intentionally does not contain an executable, consider removing the CFBundleExecutable key from its Info.plist and using a CFBundlePackageType of BNDL. If this bundle is part of a third-party framework, consider contacting the developer of the framework for an update to address this issue.

All my pod files have this issue. I tried to delete. Tried to change from FMWK to BNDL and still the same... I tried all suggestions from stackOverFlow but still the same. Anybody knows? PLSSSSS

Comment: I found a solution!

Comment: what was the solution?

Comment: @Michael Helmke, some wrong info.plist files in "Copy bundle resources".  I checked it and deleted all info.plist from there and the problem was solved! Happy coding)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by finding the named bundle in the project. just use Cmd + Shift + O and type "Info.plist then you can find the appropriate file.   remove the CFBundleExecutable key. and replace APPL by BNDL in CFBundlePackageType key. but please do not touch main Info.plist file of the project. only change in Alamofire Info.plist

Answer (score 0):

In my case I go to

**Product --> Clean Build Folder**

**Product --> Acrchive**

It's works for me.
I just clean the folder and than archive.